# NSNull boolValue getting crash objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, boolean

Crash :

> [NSNull boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b5b12878
>           2018-05-13 19:04:46.024492+0530 Doctor Express Provider[1681:579933] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b5b12878

Code :

```
NSUserDefaults *pref=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

strUserId = [pref valueForKey:PARAM_ID];
strUserToken = [pref valueForKey:PARAM_TOKEN];

NSMutableDictionary *dictparam=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictparam setObject:strUserId forKey:PARAM_ID];
[dictparam setObject:strUserToken forKey:PARAM_TOKEN];
[dictparam setObject:struser_longi forKey:PARAM_LONGITUDE];
[dictparam setObject:struser_lati forKey:PARAM_LATITUDE];
[dictparam setObject:strRequsetId forKey:PARAM_REQUEST_ID];
[dictparam setObject:@"0" forKey:PARAM_DISTANCE];
AFNHelper *afn=[[AFNHelper alloc]initWithRequestMethod:POST_METHOD];

[afn getDataFromPath:FILE_WALK_LOCATION withParamData:dictparam withBlock:^(id response, NSError *error)
{

    NSLog(@"Update Walk Location = %@",response);
    if (response)
    {
        payment=[[response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] boolValue];
        NSLog(@"Something To Print");
        NSLog(@"%d", payment);
        NSLog(@"Something To Print");

        if (payment==0)
        {
            self.lblPayment.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CARD", nil);
            self.imgCashCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card"];
        }
        else if (payment==1)
        {
            self.lblPayment.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CASH", nil);
            self.imgCashCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cash"];

        }
        if([[response valueForKey:@"success"] intValue]==1)
        {
            totalDist=[[response valueForKey:@"distance"]floatValue];
            [self.btnDistance setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %@",[[response valueForKey:@"distance"] floatValue],[response valueForKey:@"unit"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.btnDistance setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %@",[[response valueForKey:@"distance"] floatValue],[response valueForKey:@"unit"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            if ([[response valueForKey:@"is_cancelled"] integerValue]==1)
            {
                [self.timerForCancelRequest invalidate];
                [self.timerForDestinationAddr invalidate];
                NSUserDefaults *pref=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [pref removeObjectForKey:PREF_REQUEST_ID];
                [pref removeObjectForKey:PREF_NAV];
                strRequsetId=[pref valueForKey:PREF_REQUEST_ID];


                [APPDELEGATE showToastMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Request Canceled", nil) ];


                is_walker_started=0;
                is_walker_arrived=0;
                is_started=0;
                [btnWalker setHidden:NO];
                [btnArrived setHidden:YES];
                [btnWalk setHidden:YES];

                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            }
        }
    }

}];
```

Error on this line :

```
NSLog(@"Update Walk Location = %@",response);
```

> "dest_latitude" = 0;
>       "dest_longitude" = 0;
>       error = "Service not yet started";
>       "error_code" = 414;
>       "is_cancelled" = 0;
>       "payment_type" = "";
>       success = 0;
>       unit = kms;

Getting the null for payment_type...but getting crash on this line

```
payment=[[response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] boolValue];
```

Dot know how to handle that. But this print function itself not printing :

```
NSLog(@"Something To Print");
NSLog(@"%d", payment);
NSLog(@"Something To Print");
```

Any idea on how to handle this?

Updated :

```
  if([response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] != nil || ![[response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] isEqualToString:@""]){
                         payment=[[response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] boolValue];
                         NSLog(@"Something To Print");
                         NSLog(@"%d", payment);
                         NSLog(@"Something To Print");

                         if (payment==0)
                         {
                             self.lblPayment.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CARD", nil);
                             self.imgCashCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card"];
                         }
                         else if (payment==1)
                         {
                             self.lblPayment.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CASH", nil);
                             self.imgCashCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cash"];

                         }
                        }
```

Comment: @Moritz  that only, i dont know hoe to handle that..can u please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking a null value in Objective-C that has been returned from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839355/checking-a-null-value-in-objective-c-that-has-been-returned-from-a-json-string)

Comment: @Larme i checked that..but not able to check the null type before pass the value...but i can gett the values of payment as 0 or 1

Comment: If you have contact with the web developer, using a bool to determine payment if it's by cash or credit card, that strange. Because in your case, you have a third value: "unknown" (which is set as null). Would have been better a "enum" or a string, or anything else.

Comment: its not possible to contact, so only i needs to do in my code..please ..help me out..htting my head for past 1hr

Comment: "but not able to check the null type before pass the value". That's false. `payment=[[response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] boolValue];` => Is translation for `NSNumber *paymentAsNumber = [response valueForKey:@"payment_type"]; payment = [paymentAsNumber boolValue];` It's just that you are doing two calls in one line, and that's where you need to learn to separate. So check `paymentAsNumber`.

Comment: @Larme it is possible to handle in code mannully ??

Comment: Adapting from linked question and with code from previous comment: `if (paymentAsNumber == (id)[NSNull null]){payment = NO?YES?Don'tKnowwhatIsDefaultValue} else {payment = [paymentAsNumber boolValue];`

Comment: @ Larme i am very much confused..if u give me code solution with my question code its would be helpful..i can learn from that..i am new bie to this

Comment: You need to find out what instance (0x1b5b12878) is causing the crash. See eg here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403806/how-to-find-instance-by-hex-in-xcode-console

Answer (score 0):

Kiran, you can check whether payment_type is null before you get boolValue for it.

```
NSUserDefaults *pref=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

strUserId = [pref valueForKey:PARAM_ID];
strUserToken = [pref valueForKey:PARAM_TOKEN];

NSMutableDictionary *dictparam=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictparam setObject:strUserId forKey:PARAM_ID];
[dictparam setObject:strUserToken forKey:PARAM_TOKEN];
[dictparam setObject:struser_longi forKey:PARAM_LONGITUDE];
[dictparam setObject:struser_lati forKey:PARAM_LATITUDE];
[dictparam setObject:strRequsetId forKey:PARAM_REQUEST_ID];
[dictparam setObject:@"0" forKey:PARAM_DISTANCE];
AFNHelper *afn=[[AFNHelper alloc]initWithRequestMethod:POST_METHOD];

[afn getDataFromPath:FILE_WALK_LOCATION withParamData:dictparam withBlock:^(id response, NSError *error)

{

NSLog(@"Update Walk Location = %@",response);
if (response)
{
    if([response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] != nil && ![[response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] isEqualToString: ""])
    {
        payment=[[response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] boolValue];
        NSLog(@"Something To Print");
        NSLog(@"%d", payment);
        NSLog(@"Something To Print");

        if (payment==0)
        {
            self.lblPayment.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CARD", nil);
            self.imgCashCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card"];
        }
        else if (payment==1)
        {
            self.lblPayment.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CASH", nil);
            self.imgCashCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cash"];

        }
        if([[response valueForKey:@"success"] intValue]==1)
        {
            totalDist=[[response valueForKey:@"distance"]floatValue];
            [self.btnDistance setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %@",[[response valueForKey:@"distance"] floatValue],[response valueForKey:@"unit"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.btnDistance setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %@",[[response valueForKey:@"distance"] floatValue],[response valueForKey:@"unit"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            if ([[response valueForKey:@"is_cancelled"] integerValue]==1)
            {
                [self.timerForCancelRequest invalidate];
                [self.timerForDestinationAddr invalidate];
                NSUserDefaults *pref=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [pref removeObjectForKey:PREF_REQUEST_ID];
                [pref removeObjectForKey:PREF_NAV];
                strRequsetId=[pref valueForKey:PREF_REQUEST_ID];


                [APPDELEGATE showToastMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Request Canceled", nil) ];


                is_walker_started=0;
                is_walker_arrived=0;
                is_started=0;
                [btnWalker setHidden:NO];
                [btnArrived setHidden:YES];
                [btnWalk setHidden:YES];

                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            }
        }
    }
}

}];
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: @prakakta wr i needs to add..like after else statement

Comment: check my post..please..getting same again

Comment: @prakakta  [NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b5b12878
2018-05-13 20:16:22.817669+0530 Doctor Express Provider[1750:603892] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b5b12878'

Comment: i chnage the line to lie ` if([response valueForKey:@"payment_type"] != nil && ![response valueForKey:@"payment_type"])` but why this is not printing n my console`  NSLog(@"Something To Print");
                             NSLog(@"%d", payment);
                             NSLog(@"Something To Print");`

Comment: Because payment_type is not set it is nil so this is not printing something to print